# What optimization can be done on Win2008 to further increase throughput in NetTcpBinding WCF?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

Two windows server 2008 exchanging data via WCF NetTcpBinding in LAN environment. The data exchanged varies between 5k and 500k. What foptimizations can be done at the code level, at the OS TCP settings, or the Network to increase throughput?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool such as AusLogics BoostSpeed to optimize the Internet connection -- i.e., the TCP/IP configuration. Tools such as these increase the MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) of the network card or at the IP level to the maximum allowed, which is 1500 bytes for Ethernet.

There are many utilities that optimize TCP/IP on the market.

http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/boost-speed/download/